# Passing data from jQueryUI dialog form to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm new with ASP.NET/Javascript and I'm having a little trouble with the implementation of simple CRUD operations using jQueryUI dialog form. This is my code:

```
<button class="update" id="@Model.id">Update</button>
<div id="dialog-form" title="Update">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="state" id="state">
      <input type="text" name="note" id="note">
      <input type="submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
      $(function() {
          var dialog,
            state = $("#state"),
            note = $("#note"),
            id = this.id, //??
            dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              height: 400,
              width: 350,
              modal: true,
              buttons: {
                "Ok": function() {
                  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("Update","Ticket")",
                    data: {
                      id: id,
                      state: state,
                      note: note
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                      $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                    }
                  });
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                }
              }
            });

          $(".update").button().on("click", function() {
            dialog.dialog("open");
          });
        });
</script>
```

Finally the `Update` action in `TicketController`:

```
  public ActionResult Update(String id, String state, String note)
    {
        //do some stuff
    }
```

However nothing happens and it doesn't get into the action. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens ? Try run your debugger and see if you get into the Update action, or add a `error` to your `ajax`

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? The Action is empty

Comment: Your form does not include any form controls for `id` What are you expecting to pass to that parameter?

Comment: Also you have not shown what the method returns - does it return a `JsonResult` (you have specified `dataType: "json",`). And what do you want to do with the data you return - you `success` callback does not use the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `data` as below you need to pass value rather than the object by using [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
state = $("#state").val(),
note = $("#note").val(),
id = "Pass anything you wants"

data: { 'id':id,'state':state,'note':note },
```

Decorate your action method with `[HttpPost]`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(String id, String state, String note)
{
}
```

Comment: I've opened a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071012/jquery-ui-dialog-form-for-each-button-in-a-dynamic-table). Your answer is the answer for this question :)

Comment: Ooops i'm late btw you got your answer no?

Comment: Yep ty! (#random words to fill space)